# Seaborn Line Plot : Add Line and Text in the Graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to add a dot line and text to my graph.

This is my original sns.plot code.

```
# set figure size
plt.figure( figsize = ( 12, 5))

sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'weekpay',
            data = epi_raw_occ_2018_private,
            label = 'Private Workers Wage')

plt.xlabel('time')
```

I need a picture like this.[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) and [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html). You may have issues depending on the date format of your x axis, so please if you need additional support add a sample or a constructor of your dataset so that anybody can test whether a solution works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's fixed in specific value in ths x-axis. Then this should do:

`plt.axvline('2020-02-01',linestyle='.')`

As for the text you could add:

`plt.text('2020-03-01',1100,"this is the text that will be added")`

You should fix the first array to match the desired x-axis and then on the y-axis no argument so it goes aling the full chart. An alternative is using `weekpay`'s `min()` and `max()` values for the y-axis in order to make the line cover the most of it. Finally `linestyle='.'` is what makes it a dotted line.

Comment: Is this the right code? I tried but failed..

plt.axvline([date=='2020-02-01',linestyle=='.'])

plt.text(date=='2020-03-01',1100,"this is the text that will be added")

Comment: I dont think yiu need to pass a list or a condition. I had a typo in my answer which I corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.